# HTML5 Canvas add id or class

Tags: jquery, canvas

I'm drawing on Canvas.
Example:

```
       '1.01': {
        color: 'pink',
        points: [563,69,630,69,630,149,563,149]
      },
```

Where 1.01 is the text displayed in a tooltip when you hover over it. Points are `x` and `y` coordinates to create a block on the canvas. 
Is it possible to give this drawn block an `id` or a `class` so that I can handle it in jQuery?

Comment: Canvas is just an area filled with pixels, if you want your elements to be in the DOM you should opt for SVG instead. (There are lots of ways of making canvas interactive though)

Answer (score 0):

How about you store it in its own object and then hold a collection of these objects for later use?  Although I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "handle it in jQuery" because on the canvas, you're simple filling pixel areas, which is very different from when working with the DOM.

```
var block = function (color, points) {
    return {
        color: color,
        points: points
    };
};

var b1 = block('pink', [563,69,630,69,630,149,563,149]);
// Do whatever you need with it...
```

And replace your code with the following to keep the same reference:

```
'1.01': b1,
```